# Does a column produce horizontal thrust?

Tags: structural-engineering

For a single 4x4 wood column loaded with say 300lbs of weight is there any horizontal thrust being generated in any direction? Columns don't seem to be referenced in this manual.

[Engineering Wiki - Civil Engineering](http://www.engineeringwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Columns can and do create horizontal reaction if that's what you mean.

Some examples are:

- A column loaded by a vertical force not passing through its axial center.
- A column rigidly or semi-rigidly connected to a beam.
- A column adjacent to a non-structural member such as a partition wall, incidental stacked material such as in a storage.
- A column subject to lateral forces of a shear strap or lateral force of shear wall.
- A column not loaded symmetrically.